# How to create a custom write.table function?

Tags: r, write.table

I can use write.table function to create an output data from a data.frame:

```
> write.table(head(cars), sep = "|", row.names=FALSE)
"speed"|"dist"
4|2
4|10
7|4
7|22
8|16
9|10
```

How can I create my own write.table function which creates an output like this (header with double pipes and data with preceding and succeeding pipes)?:

```
||"speed"||"dist"||
|4|2|
|4|10|
|7|4|
|7|22|
|8|16|
|9|10|
```

Comment: Have a look at the code of `write.table`. Do you want this function for writing to a file or displaying on screen?

Comment: I want it to write into a file, e.g. write.table(head(cars), sep = "|", file = "myfile.sep")

Comment: can you explain `||"speed"||"dist"||` (I understand the first double-pipe as there is an extra column of  row numbers  in the data but not in the header). But what's the function of the other two `||`? So you have 6 separators in the header but only 4 in data? Otherwise, something  like `write.pipetable <- function(obj, file) write.table(obj, file, sep="|")` is the likely answer. (Plus if you really need extra separators at the end and beginnig of the lines, you could add just empty columns to the left and right, and use `na=""` -

Comment: - and to have equal number of separators in the header and data, you could add row numbers as a variable in the data frame and use `row.names=FALSE` in `write.table`

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write.table` can get you part of the way, but you will still need to do some fiddling around to get things to work just as you want.

Here's an example:

```
x <- capture.output(
  write.table(head(cars), sep = "|", row.names = FALSE, eol = "|\n"))
x2 <- paste0("|", x)
x2[1] <- gsub("|", "||", x2[1], fixed=TRUE)
cat(x2, sep = "\n")
# ||"speed"||"dist"||
# |4|2|
# |4|10|
# |7|4|
# |7|22|
# |8|16|
# |9|10|
```

As a function, I guess in its most basic form it could look something like:

```
write.myOut <- function(inDF, outputFile) {
  x <- capture.output(
    write.table(inDF, sep = "|", row.names = FALSE, eol = "|\n"))
  x <- paste0("|", x)
  x[1] <- gsub("|", "||", x[1], fixed=TRUE)
  cat(x, sep = "\n", file=outputFile)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible with `write.table`. Here is a workaround:

```
# function for formatting a row
rowFun <- function(x, sep = "|") {
  paste0(sep, paste(x, collapse = sep), sep)
}

# create strings
rows <- apply(head(cars), 1, rowFun)
header <- rowFun(gsub("^|(.)$", "\\1\"", names(head(cars))), sep = "||")

# combine header and row strings
vec <- c(header, rows)

# write the vector
write(vec, sep = "\n", file = "myfile.sep")
```

The resulting file:

```
||"speed"||"dist"||
|4|2|
|4|10|
|7|4|
|7|22|
|8|16|
|9|10|
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the header of data values contain a `|` character?  Or if the header values contain a `"` character?

Comment: @RichieCotton Only the OP can answer this question. With the provided code, `|`s and `"`s will be preserved.